# Do I get two different certificate cards if I earn both a pilot and a ground instructor certificate in the US?

Tags: faa-regulations, pilot-certification, cfi

I would like to know if one will be receiving two separate licenses in case he/she earns a pilot certificate as well as a ground instructor certificate in the US.

Do the certificates come separately on two different plastic cards? If yes, does the certificate number change between them, or do they have the same number?

Comment: Commercial pilot certificate, CFI, and AGI; three different cards.  Same number on pilot and AGI, and the same number plus *'CFI'* on the CFI certificate ie.  1234567 vs. 1234567CFI.

Comment: Which country are you asking about?

Comment: I just improved the question. It is for US.

Comment: Following up on @JLynn (deleted post). It's possible that multi-certificate holders currently have a different number on each of two certificates.  For many years a person's SSN was used as a cert number.  If you did not request a replacement cert for the cert with a SSN number then you could have certs with different numbers after acquiring a new type cert (e.g., getting a new AGI cert would have a non-SSN number and your older private pilot could be using your SSN. ) Here is a helpful link: https://www.faa.gov/licenses_certificates/airmen_certification/change_certificate_number/

Answer (score 4):

**Yes.**. The certificate number will not change.  The flight instructor certificate includes `CFI` at the end of your number.

> [§61.5](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=cebd1cb1e877f06442e80f297e00df52&mc=true&node=se14.2.61_15&rgn=div8)   Certificates and ratings issued under this part.
>   (a) The following certificates are issued under this part to an applicant who satisfactorily accomplishes the training and certification requirements for the certificate sought:
>
> (1) Pilot certificates
>
> (2) Flight instructor certificates.
>
> (3) Ground instructor certificates.

[Part 63](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=cebd1cb1e877f06442e80f297e00df52&mc=true&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr63_main_02.tpl) provides guidances on flight engineer and flight navigator certificates.

[Part 65](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=cebd1cb1e877f06442e80f297e00df52&mc=true&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14cfr65_main_02.tpl) provides guidance for ATC tower personnel, mechanics, repairman, parachute riggers, and dispatcher certificates.